# Connecting to MySQL from and Objective-C application

Tags: mysql, objective-c

How do you connect to MySQL from within an Objective-C application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [MySQL C API](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/c.html) directly. If you need an example you can look at the source code of [Sequel Pro](http://code.google.com/p/sequel-pro/), an open-source MySQL management tool.

Comment: Thanks Sven. Do you know if that API is distributed with Mac OS X, or do you have to download the source code?